# Окно скрыто в предпросмотре конструктора c# wpf netcore

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

Во всех проектах на netcore такая история, как на скрине, даже которые не трогал до появления проблемы.
если новый проект создать, то все нормально.
Нагуглил только удаление папки obj или смена разрядности процессора. Ничего из этого не помогло.
Сама программа компилируется и отображается как надо.
[image]

студия 2019 со всеми обновлениями.
в бленде то же самое
Подскажете что-нибудь?

Comment: при добавлении нового окна в проект - в нем то же самое.

Comment: попробуйте папку .vs(скрытая, должна быть рядом с sln) еще удалить

Comment: Я удалил, запустил проект, ничего не исправилось, потом потыкал все, покрутил масштаб и появилось окно.(до этого уже много всего пробовал, не помогало)
не знаю, ваш совет помог или нет, но в любом случае - спасибо.

Comment: мдэ. вчера не внимательно все проверил. ничего не исправилось.
исправилось только визуально, если размер окна изменить и покрутить колесико(но элементов интерфейса нету в окне)
и при перезапуске опять то же самое, что на картинке

Comment: Вы случаем не используете `WindowStyle=None`? Кастомные окна, быть какой-нибудь NuGet пакет на всех проектах один и тот же? Сколько подобных историй видел, ни в одной причной не была непонятная мистика. :) Дело в том, что конструктор класса окна в .Net Core выполняется дизайнером форм как при запуске программы с самой настоящей инициализацией компонентов. С одной лишь разницей, не вызываются никакие события. Другими словами, причиной может быть код вашего проекта.

Comment: Ну да, там подключены стили на все окна. Core.xaml и Brashes.xaml файлы. Я их создал и подключил еще в самом начале и ничего больше не менял. Сломалось, кажись, после обновления студии почти на полтора- 2 гига(долго не обновлял).
тогда как это исправить? В самой программе-то все норм. Обычное окно. И стили как надо. Конечно, предпросмотр - не самая важная вещь, но я уже привык, удобно для наглядности.

Comment: Для интереса удалил подключение этих стилей из App.xaml, и правда из-за этого. Но я хочу использовать эти стили)

Comment: Так. У меня в Core.xaml, который и подключается, было подчеркнуто clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib
Заменил mscorlib на System и заработало:) Хотя все равно осталось подчеркнутым с той же ошибкой. 
Спасибо больше:) Эх, мог бы сам догадаться, что разница между абсолютно новым проектом и старыми - только в стилях подключенных.